# How to fix or report such fixing requests?

Tags: support

Tag comparitor needs to be fixed. Somehow whoever created misspelled the word.

https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/comparitor

How to fix or report such fixing requests?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, This one is fairly simple. I went ahead and took care of it, but it's something practically everyone can do.

Someone misspelled the tag (not clicking on the suggested existing [comparator](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/comparator) tag). So edit the tags on the one question that has that tag, and change it from [comparitor](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/comparitor) to [comparator](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/comparator). The system will automatically purge tags with zero questions in due time. If it's something more serious than 2-3 tags, then that would be a good time to bring it to Meta or notify a moderator.

Comment: Good to know that the system automatically sweeps the unused tags.

Comment: @ChetanBhargava It sweeps single use tags on a 6 month interval also.